# How to plot a contour in the plane defined by a vector cross-product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I have some contours of a structure in 3D that I would like to plot in 2D, but how do I get from 3D to 2D? In other words, I would like to plot the contour in the plane defined by the cross-product of three points from the contour.
For instance it could be the contours of a ship.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $z=0$ for every point would project every point onto the $xy$-plane. You could also choose $x=0$ to project onto the $yz$-plane, or $y=0$ to project onto the $xz$-plane, or set any other fixed linear combination of the coordinates to zero to project onto another plane, whose orientation depends on the choice of the coefficients of that linear combination.

Comment: The problem is that the plane cannot be static... It has to change with the contour. If we have contours around a sphere for instance, and you look at all the contours from the plane y=0 the contours will only be a line at some point. In this particular example I would want all contours to look the same in 2D.